# sa_handler : cannot assign a value of type "void" to an entity of type "void (*)(int)"

Tags: c, unix

I'm doing a work for school, this example works on a Linux machine.
I'm trying it on my Mac but it doesn't work, and as I know this should work but I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct sigaction act_fils, act_pere;

int pid;
void fonction_fils() {
    printf("Temperature : %d", rand() % 31 + 10);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void fonction_pere() {
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1); // Permet d'envoyer un signal au fils 
    alarm(5);
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        act_fils.sa_handler = fonction_fils();
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act_fils, NULL);
        while (1) {
            pause();
        }
    } else {
        act_pere.sa_handler = fonction_pere();
        sigaction(SIGALRM, &act_pere, NULL);
        alarm(5);
        while (1) {
            sleep(1);
            printf("-");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

And this is the error
`cannot assign a value of type "void" to an entity of type "void (*)(int)"` on the `sa_handler`.

Can you help me please?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please give the exact full error. It should have a line number and show the problematic line of code.

Comment: Re “this example works on a Linux machine”: That is doubtful. It is unlikely you used a C implementation on any machine that allowed you to assign a value of type `void` to a pointer, and, in the code as shown, `fonction_fils()` has type `void`. There is almost certainly something different between what you tried on Linux and what you tried on a Mac, and you ought to look into that, in addition to fixing the errors identified in the answers below.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, when a signal handler is registered, the function isn't supposed to be called at that time. Rather, a pointer to the function is required: the pointer is stored into the `sigaction` structure:

```
act_fils.sa_handler= fonction_fils; // no function call () parentheses
```

We want the funtion itself, not the return value from a call to the function.

Secondly, the function has to have the right type for a signal handler:

```
void fonction_fils(int sig)
{
}
```

Note that in the C language, unlike C++, if you declare a function paramter list as `()`, it declares the function as having an unknown parameter type information. The function *definition* is one that takes no arguments, compatible with `(void)`, but as a declaration it doesn't say that to the surrounding program.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of statements like these

```
act_fils.sa_handler= fonction_fils();
```

and

```
act_pere.sa_handler=fonction_pere();
```

where there are used function calls that have the return type void you need to write

```
act_fils.sa_handler= fonction_fils;
```

and

```
act_pere.sa_handler=fonction_pere;
```

to assign function pointers.

Pay attention to that for example the data member `sa_handler` has the type

```
void     (*sa_handler)(int);
```

So the corresponding function shall have the same type.

From the documentation

```
  sa_handler specifies the action to be associated with signum and
   is be one of the following:

   * SIG_DFL for the default action.

   * SIG_IGN to ignore this signal.

   * A pointer to a signal handling function.  This function
     receives the signal number as its only argument.
```

Comment: Thanks the error disappears but, when the program runs it should show 4 "-" and a random number. Instead it shows me 4 "-" and "zsh: alarm", then it stops. Do you know why ?

Comment: @DamienDne See also my updated answer.

Comment: I see, so I change my functions to "void* fonction_fils" so it has the same type, but I'm having the same prob as I  answered you.

Comment: @DamienDne The function type shall be void( int )

Comment: Oh I found out ! I use the @Kaz comment also and it works. Thanks a lot both of you !